# How to automate “Read Values” tab in SPSS Modeler?

Tags: transpose, spss-modeler

I am working on fully automating a model I have created in SPSS Modeler. My model consists of source nodes that get updated everytime I run the scripts. The datamodel then goes through multiple node including a transpose node. Though, everytime the datamodel is updated, I have to manually press "Read Values" tab to grab the updated fields otherwise SPSS creates an error. I need to know is there any way to automate the "Read Values" tab function?

Answer (score 0):

There is to my knowledge no way to automate the "Read Values" button function. The only way to trigger the node to read the values is to manually click it each time.